# Making a specified column not to be draggable in Nattable

Tags: nattable

how to make a specified column not to be draggable and droppable in Nattable.for eg.I want to make Column that has index 1 not to be draggable and droppable.I saw ILayer getCellByPosition(int colpos,int rowpos)but I can't make that ICell not to be draggable.How to do it?If someone knows,please share to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom ColumnReorderDragMode and override mouseDown() so it doesn't do anything for the columns that shouldn't be draggable. Register that ColumnReorderDragMode to a top layer, like the GridLayer.

Also see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781877/ where this question was already asked and answered in a bit more detail.